# Cordova 3.0.1 Not building Android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to add android to my project but I keep getting this error, I am on a mac and I have no idea where the tools/ folder is so put the SDK which I downloaded.

```
sudo cordova platform add android
    [Error: The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your path. Output: /bin/sh: android: command not found
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hva you tried to skip this command and just do a cordova build android?

Comment: yes and does not work I get Installed platforms: firefoxos, ios 3.1.0
Available platforms: android, blackberry10

Comment: If you have installed the android SDK you can find it on your mac with this terminal command: "sudo find / -name zipalign -print"